# Laravel Spatie syntax error, unexpected token "readonly"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm getting this error anyone knows how to fix this?

It's working fine on the local server but when we set up on serverless server it throws this error.

`syntax error, unexpected token "readonly" (View: /workspace/resources/views/backend/teams/form.blade.php)`

in /workspace/vendor/spatie/laravel-html/src/Elements/Input.php (line 23)

```
    use Autofocus;    
    use Disabled;    
    use MinMaxLength;    
    use Name;    
    use Placeholder;    
    use Readonly;    
    use Required;    
    use Type;    
    use Value;
```

use Readonly; is line 23

Comment: PHP 8.1 introduces `readonly` as part of the language https://wiki.php.net/rfc/readonly_properties_v2

Comment: Readonly has been change to ReadonlyTrait you can see here : https://github.com/spatie/laravel-html/blob/main/src/Elements/Input.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with PHP 8.1 as @Nigel Ren mentioned, readonly is now part of the language. I downgraded the PHP version to 7.4 and it started working.

But, if you are fine with updating the library that's the correct solution for it.

Comment: Using an end-of-life version of software is not any kind of answer. You simply update the library that is using invalid names; they fixed this in July.

Comment: @miken32 updating will break the code and I don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the issue is compatibility of PHP version between PHP7.4 and PHP8.0 or higher.

I have tried with **--ignore-platform-reqs**, as followed,

```
composer require spatie/laravel-html --ignore-platform-reqs
```

It works for me.
Otherwise you need to setup a fresh laravel and migration your existing models, controllers and view files. All the best.
Thanks.